# Can you find which instance of a multiset contains a given iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, multiset

Suppose I have several multiset instances and I'm given an iterator, `it`, to one of the instances, but I am not told which instance this iterator belongs to. For each instance, is there a O(1) way to determine whether this iterator belongs to this instance or not? To do that, I think the multiset container must include some sort of hash table for the iterators it holds, but I don't believe the STL library does that.

I could not find an function that would do this in the documentation, so the only approach that I can think of is to first deference the given iterator and use `instance.find(*it)`, and if it's found we use `std::multiset::equal_range` to do a linear search to see if one of the iterators pointing to the same value is the given iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no there isn't. Furthermore, it is undefined behavor to use an iterator, in some form or fashion, with a container that it doesn't come from. Finally, comparing two iterators from different containers is also undefined behavior, so the workaround you described is also undefined behavior.

The above applies to all containers in the C++ library, not just a multiset.

The objects referenced by your iterators will need to reference, in some form or fashion, which container they are a part of; there aren't any other practical alternatives.

Comment: When you say "containers," you mean different instances of the same container and not different types yet? I've always thought "containers" meant things like vectors, sets, maps, etc... and not instances of a vector or set, etc...

Comment: The term "container" is mostly interchangeable, and can refer to either discrete templates, or instances of those templates. As I use it here, it refers to specific instances of template classes. Just like the term "car" can refer to any contraption that has four wheels, a couple of doors, a few seats, a steering wheel, and a few other common features; and it can also refer to the specific, individual hunk of rust in your driveway.